# Equivalent of JsonExtensionData for form data binding in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

If we want to bind all unrecognizable properties from request body we can use `JsonExtensionData` attribute. But it's for JSON, so only for binding from `application/json` Content-Type.

I want to achieve the same but for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I cant find any equivalent of `JsonExtensionData` attribute but for form data.

Also, if there is no any equivalent I can write my own binder. But how can I create my custom binder for properties in ASP NET Core?

Comment: could you show some codes that you've tried?